# RegEx a-z0-9 pattern in java

Tags: java, regex

Sorry to ask such a basic question but I cannot find the answer.  I want to match a string that only allows a-z0-9.  The alphas and digits prescence are optional but not other characters should be there.  The string should be compatible with the regex implemented by Ziath.

Comment: Please post your own attempts so we can help

Comment: I tried ^[a-z0-9]*, [a-z0-9], ^[a-z0-9]+$, [a-z0-9] then I tried searching on the web and got ^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ , ^[a-z][-a-z0-9\._]*$ and (?<=function\s*)[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?=\s*\() though I think the last one is some kind of .NET special thing.  My test strings are eeeeeeeee333e
eeeeeeeee333.
1111111111111
62222222252242
123456789012q
abcd1234
a1
1a
1
A
1 a a££££$$$ a

Comment: I see you tried `^[a-z0-9]+$` that was my guess as well